# Create expression from reflected type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, expression, expression-trees

I have a method signature like this:

```
IPostprocessComposer<T> Without<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertyPicker)
```

Example usage:

```
AutoFixture.Build<Request>()
                            .Without(p => p.ID)
                            .Create();
```

I want to create a more flexible solution and always ignore a few properties from the type (in this case "Request") identified via reflection

My (not working) solution:

```
IPostprocessComposer<T> row = fixture.Build<T>();

var primitivePropertiesToIgnore = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(p => p.Name.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("id") || p.Name.ToLowerInvariant().EndsWith("id"));

foreach (var primitiveProperty in primitivePropertiesToIgnore)
{
    var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var expr = Expression.Lambda(Expression.PropertyOrField(x, primitiveProperty.Name), x);

    // This line is working, but of course I need "int" to be a generic type here... how can i achieve this?
    row = row.Without((Expression<Func<T, int>>)expr);
}
```

Question:
I guess the expression must be somehow differently passed to the Without method in order to work? But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to make this work is to use `dynamic`:

```
row = row.Without((dynamic)expr);
```

Since `row` is already statically typed, the dynamic behavior will be contained to only this statement.

If you didn't want to use `dynamic`, you would need to use reflection to invoke the `Without` method with the right type parameters, but I don't see any advantage in doing that (it's more complicated, but it isn't any more type-safe).